# A question about approximations.

Tags: physics, approximation

We use approximations because they give a neat and clean answer and they are quite useful in physical situations too. For example, we can write: $\frac {5} {1000 + 0.15}$ as $\frac{5} {1000}$ , because both fractions are different only by $0.000000074988$, which is quite small if we are making some calculations for physical situations.
I'm having a doubt about when we can and when we can't just remove the *very small* term which is in addition or subtraction. For instance, it is a general thing to do $$ \frac {a} {b+c} = \frac {a} {b} \text{ if } b\gg c$$

Now, let me explain my doubt through an example of physics:

**Electric field due to a continuous line of charge of length $2L$ at a point $z$ above it's midpoint is given by** ($\lambda$ the  being line charge density) $$ \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}~~\frac {2\lambda L} {z \sqrt{z^2 +L^2} } $$ now if $z\gt\gt L$ then we have , $$ \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} ~~ \frac {2\lambda L } {z^2 } $$ considering $L^2 = 0$ and this is quite consistent with the intuition that if we are too far away from the line it would look to us like a point charge with the total charge of $\lambda ~2L$.

**Electric field due to continuous surface charge of circular disk of radius R (with surface charge density $\sigma$) at a point $z$ above it's center is given by**  :- $$ \frac {1} {2\epsilon_0} ~~ \sigma z ~~\left[ \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2} }\right]$$  now if $z\gt\gt R$ and if we mechanically remove $R^2 $ by considering it too small we would get $0$ which is quite non-intuitive because if we go far far away from that disk we will see that all the charge is concentrated at the center and the formula should become $$ \frac{1} {4 \pi\epsilon_0} ~~ \frac  {\sigma \pi R^2 ~z}{z^2} $$ but we won't get it if we put $R^2 = 0$ . My question is why we can't do this here but can do it above?

Comment: But you're multiplying by $z\gt\gt R$ so this difference is not necessarily small enough to ignore.

Comment: Be careful when using approximation when you subtract numbers. Say you are at night, and you see the Moon rising next to the neighbor's house across the street. Both of you can agree that the distance from your respective houses to the Moon are about $238900$ miles. If you subtract those, you get $0$. But there is obviously some distance between your houses.

Comment: @Andrei Yes, you are right. So, what should we do? Always take the Taylor Expansion?

Comment: @PeterForeman Can you please elaborate just a little ? I mean in which step I'm multiplying by $ z\gt\gt R$ ?

Comment: Yes, until you get a difference.

Comment: @Andrei You mean difference of first degree?

Comment: @adeshmishra Say you have the Taylor expansion function of function 1 as $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$ and $b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+...$ for function 2. If you subtract the two, you should use all terms up to and including the first time $a_i\ne b_i$. So for example $a_0=b_0$ and $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$ and $a_3\ne b_3$, then, for small $x$, the difference will be approximately $(a_3-b_3)x^3$

Comment: I think the nice rule of thumb here is that when we're doing asymptotics, we want the leading order term, whatever that is. It could happen that the leading order term is actually small, but that doesn't mean that $0$ is actually a good approximation for it. So in your second example for instance, it doesn't make sense to completely neglect $R$ because then you get an approximate electric field of just zero. Even if you weren't multiplying by $z$ on the outside, you would still want to resolve that inner part correctly to leading order rather than discarding it entirely.

Comment: @adeshmishra $$\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma\boxed{z}(\dots)$$

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes I’m getting you. Do you mean that $z$ is too big that the difference is getting compensated? I mean if $\frac{1}{z} ~~ - \frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2 +R^2}} $ is small enough but after we multiply it by a big $z$ it’s not ignorable.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for giving a rule of thumb, but I’m getting some problem understanding the terminologies like ‘asymptotics’ , ‘leading order terms’ . I request you please write an answer because that would be much easier for me to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Similar to Botond's answer.*

Considering 
$$y=z \left( \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2} }\right)=1- \frac{z}{\sqrt{R^2 + z^2}}=1-\sqrt{\frac{z^2}{{R^2 + z^2}} }=1-\sqrt{1-\frac{R^2}{{R^2 + z^2}} }$$

Now, using long division or Taylor series for large values of $z$
$$\frac{R^2}{R^2 + z^2}=\frac{R^2}{z^2}-\frac{R^4}{z^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{1-\frac{R^2}{{R^2 + z^2}} }=\sqrt{1-\frac{R^2}{z^2}+\frac{R^4}{z^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)}=1-\frac{R^2}{2 z^2}+\frac{3 R^4}{8 z^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)$$ which makes
$$y=\frac{R^2}{2 z^2}-\frac{3 R^4}{8 z^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)=\frac{R^2}{2 z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^4}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

We don't just put $L=0$ in the first equation: We take the first (non-zero) term from the Taylor expansion. For your second formula, you can use the generalised Binomial theorem:
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{\alpha}{n} x^n$$
Which means that
$$(1+x)^{-1/2} \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}x$$
HINT:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2(1+R^2/z^2)}}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+R^2/z^2}}=\frac{1}{z}(1+R^2/z^2)^{-1/2}$$